# scraping data from json after using requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i am trying to extract specific data from requested json file

so after passing Authorization and using requests.get i got my request , i think it is called dictionary for python coders and called json for javascript coders
it containt too much information that i dont need and i would like to extract one or two only
for example {"bio" : " hello world " }
and that json file contains more that one " bio " 
for example i am scraping 100 accounts and i would like to extract all " bio " in one code

so i tried this :

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {"Authorization" : "xxxx"}
req = requests.get('website', headers = headers)
data = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

titles = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'bio'})
for title in titles :
    print(title.text)
```

and didnt work , i tried multiple ideas with no success
if possible please write me a code that i can understande since iam trying to learn more about my mistakes

thanks

Comment: "and didnt work" is not specific enough. Did you get errors? If so, please include the full error message in your post. Did you get unexpected behaviour? If so, please describe the desired behaviour and how it differs from the one you're actually experiencing.

Comment: no error but doesnt print what i asked for like it is not there , when i checked the file so many lines have " bio "

Comment: Please post a sample of `soup.prettify()`

Comment: {"last":false,"prev":"0","next":"2019-07-12T09:36:23.653Z_36910299","followers":[{"id":"32bcd8b6a09547e6ab799acfd9e35336","bio":"","blocked":false,"coverPhot

Comment: Is there a `<span>` tag in this output? I don't think so because this is JSON, not HTML. If it _is_ JSON, `BeautifulSoup` is the wrong tool to use because it's an HTML parser. You can parse JSON with the built-in `json` module or simply retrieve the dictionary with `req.json()`.

Comment: great , so i searched about topics helping me to * find all ) inside a json and didnt fine a solution , can you suggest me ? i tried `req.json()['followers']['bio']` and it works but it gets only the first " bio " , i want to search for all " bio " weather is is inside `[followers]`  or not

Comment: You shouldn't've been able to do `req.json()['followers']['bio']` in the first place since it looks like `req.json()['followers']` is a _list_ which cannot be indexed by strings at all. If it _is_ a list, you cal loop over its elements and get the `'bio'` of each of them.

Answer (score 1):

The `Aphid` library I created is perfect for this.

from command-prompt

```py
py -m pip install Aphid
```

Then its just as easy as loading your json data and searching it with aphid.

```
import json
import Aphid

resp = requests.get(yoururl)
data = json.loads(resp.text)

results = Aphid.findall(data, 'bio')
```

`results` is now equal to a list of tuples(key, value), of every occurence of the 'bio' key.

Comment: I recommend you clearly indicate that this is your library, it can be considered SPAM

Comment: read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298734/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-my-own-library-as-part-of-a-real-answer

Answer (score 0):

After you get your request either:

- you get a simple json file (in which case you import it to python using [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)) **or**
- you get an html file from which you can extract the json code (using BeautifulSoup) which in turn you will parse using json library.